# Should questions be edited to show images in-line?

Tags: discussion, editing, images

Looking at the first version of [this](https://superuser.com/q/190663) question.

The image link provided in the question points to an imgur URL, so probably was uploaded using the magic now built in to the site.

So, should this be edited to show the image inline with the question?
I'm interested in a general answer, not just for this specific question, so I can edit more effectively in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I generally make it a point to ensure that if a question has an image link, then a preview/thumbnail of it is available. More often than not, it's enough to tell what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you simply check the link works? Or that you would move also move the image inline?

Comment: I shpould've been more clear, I'd move the image inline.